# NotePad++ автоматически ставить ";" в конце строки

Tags: notepad++

Вопрос конечно глупый. Я на работе пишу на FoxPro. Там свой синтаксис. Дома я пишу на PHP в редакторе NotePad++. Но после 6 часов на FoxPro я иногда забываю ставить ";" (точка с запятой) в конце строки команды. Можно как-то "научить" NotePad++ автоматически выставлять точку с запятой, если я пишу php-код (java). И если так можно сделать, то можно ли еще как-то "научить" NotePad++ подсвечивать переменные без "$" в начале. А то тоже иногда забываю писать. Просто потом много времени теряю на дебуг кода из-за таких механических ошибок. Спасибо если поможете.

Comment: В PHP операторы могут быть многострочными, и ";" в конце _каждой_ строки тебя уж точно не обрадует. А плагинить полный синтаксический анализатор в NPP вряд ли кто-то сподобился. То же относится и к необходимости отличать имена переменных от имён других элементов программы.

Comment: `если я пишу php-код (java)` - вот тут вообще не понял к чему java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ - это не IDE, а просто расширенный блокнот.
Вы можете расставить точки с запятой с помощью регулярных выражений и замены текста. Если необходима проверка кода (синтаксический анализ) в процессе разработки, используйте IDE. Eclipse, Netbeans, продукты JetBrains или что то еще. Они отлично подсвечивают ошибки.